# Download a text file of items in the global environment

Tags: r

What to do when you have a lot of individual objects in the global environment and you want to save them as a table of values?

I could not find any similar questions here, but found and an answer in the R help files eventually. It's posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The `dump` function in base R did the trick. I used `dump(ls(), "my_file_name.txt")`

It produces a text file that you can edit pretty easily. I used a macro in notepad++ to replace the `<-` items and delete the line break, resulting in a file I could easily copy and paste into a table.

There's probably a better way. Other answers are more than welcome.